# Derivation of the formula for E(MSE) in Recursive Partitioning for Heterogeneous Causal Effects (Athey and Imben 2015)

Tags: variance, econometrics, causality, cart, treatment-effect

[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/420529/formula-for-emse-from-recursive-partitioning-for-heterogeneous-causal-effects) answers a question from the [Recursive Partitioning for Heterogeneous Causal Effects](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.01132.pdf) paper by Athey and Imbens.

However, I am blocked at an even earlier stage from the previous post. I don't understand how they derive the second equality in the attached formula, p7 from the arXiv paper.

I have some E(-2 * Y_i* mu_(x_i)) that do not go out in my expansion, so I guess I am doing it all wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks in advance :)

Timothée[image]